# Slider function while using PlutoUI and CairoMakie

Tags: package, julia

I want to use the Slider function as used in PlutoUI, however I also use the CairoMakie package. When I run my code, I am informed that because the command "Slider" is used by both packages the use of it should be qualified. However, I don't know how to ensure this:

My code:
``` md"Balance between complete and ring network ``\theta``: $(@bind frac_interaction_interbank Slider(0:0.1:1, show_value = true, default = 0))" ```

When I run this i get this warning message:
`WARNING: both CairoMakie and PlutoUI export "Slider"; uses of it in module workspace#7 must be qualified`

Thus: how can I use the Slider function as used in PlutoUI, while using both PlutoUI and CairoMakie?

Answer (score 1):

Try `PlutoUI.Slider(0:0.1:1)`

The warning means both packages define a function called "Slider". Qualifying (in this context) means specifying which package's definition you're calling.